# Naming Convention For Data Attribute Value When Used Specifically for Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For the Data Attribute *Value*, is it convention to use *hyphens* or *camelCase*?

**Hyphen Example:**

```
<input type="text" name="some_input"  data-target="to-grab-input-via-javascript">
```

**Camel Case Example**

```
<input type="text" name="some_input"  data-target="toGrabInputViaJavaScript">
```

A google search brings up the naming conventions on the data attribute itself, but not the naming convention on the data attribute's *value*. All examples I found only had one word for the data attribute value as well, so I could not find an answer to this question.

Javascript likes things camel cased, so I would imagine it should be camel cased, but I do not want to make an assumption.

Comment: There is no standard convention. But, definitely do no use smart quotes (`“”`) when coding.

Comment: @ScottMarcus are you saying that there shouldn't be double quotes around the data attribute value?  Are you suggesting single quotes instead, or something else?

Comment: Back in XML/XSLT days, we used kebab-case everywhere in HTML and CSS, and camelCase in Javascript and JSON.

Comment: Your question uses formatted "smart" quotes (`“”`), rather than straight quotes: `""`. This can cause problems with character encoding. Never use richly formatted text in source code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus ahh, updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no standard on this. Use what is most comfortable for you, but be aware that when retrieving the value with the **[`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)**, dashed values will be converted to camel case and vice versa:

> **Name conversion**
>
> **dash-style to camelCase:**
>
> A custom data attribute name
>   is transformed to a key for the DOMStringMap entry with the following
>   rules
>
> - the prefix `data-` is removed (including the dash);
> - for any dash (`U+002D`) followed by an ASCII lowercase letter `a` to `z`, the dash is removed and the letter is transformed into its uppercase counterpart;
> - other characters (including other dashes) are left unchanged.
>
> **camelCase to dash-style:**
>
> The opposite transformation, that maps a key
>   to an attribute name, uses the following rules:
>
> - Restriction: A dash must not be immediately followed by an ASCII
>     lowercase letter `a` to `z` (before the transformation);
> - a prefix `data-` is added;
> - any ASCII uppercase letter `A` to `Z` is transformed into a dash
>     followed by its lowercase counterpart;
> - other characters are left
>     unchanged.
>
> The restriction in the rules above ensures that the two
>   transformations are the inverse one of the other.
>
> For example, the attribute named `data-abc-def` corresponds to the key `abcDef`.

Here are some other examples:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("d1").dataset); // "data-this-is-a-test" becomes "thisIsATest"
console.log(document.getElementById("d2").dataset); // "data-thisIsATest" becomes "thisisatest"
```

```html
<div id="d1" data-this-is-a-test="foo"></div>
<div id="d2" data-thisIsATest="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Is there any convention for the value? 

```HTML
<div id="d1" data-this-is-a-test="foo-bar"></div>
<-- vs (or any other case) -->
<div id="d1" data-this-is-a-test="fooBar"></div>
```

Comment: @MrKey It depends on what the data represents, so if it were to represent something that typically follows a naming convention, then yes, apply that convention. But, in general, no, because the value of a `data-*` attribute is completely user-driven. It's your data, you can structure it any way you need/want to.