# Removing data attributes in HTML file with pandoc lua filter

Tags: lua, pandoc, quarto

When compiling a document from Quarto, there are some divs with `data-` attribute values that I'd like to remove. These have specific names like `data-output_encrypt`:

```html
<div class="cell" data-output_encrypt="key1">
...
</div>
```

Based on examples I've seen in the docs, etc, I'm imagining the lua filter will look something like this:

```lua
if FORMAT:match 'html' then
  function Div (elem)
    elem.attributes.data-output_encrypt = nil
    return elem
  end
end
```

...but this leads to a syntax error:

```
ERROR: remove_data.lua:3: syntax error near '-'
```

I'm guessing because attribute names can't contain hyphens (because they are table keys?). I know I'm on the right track because I can set arbitrary attributes without hyphens (e.g., "data"); I'm just not sure how to deal with the hyphen.

How can I modify/delete the `data-output_encrypt` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to note here.

Firstly, attributes name in pandoc Div are prefixed with `data-` when converted into HTML div tag attributes. So to access them with lua filter you do the table indexing by using only the part after `data-` as a key.

Secondly, `elem.attributes` is actually a lua table with attribute names as keys and attribute values as values corresponding to the table keys. And to access a value, you can either use `table[key]` syntax, where `key` could be numeric, string or any value except `nil` or `NaN`, or **if the key is a string constant, you can use it as `table. Key` where this is only valid if the string consists of underscores, letters, and numbers, but shouldn't start with a number.** ([See here for details with example](https://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial))

So either of the below should work,

```lua
elem.attributes.output_encrypt = nil
-- or
elem.attributes["output_encrypt"] = nil
```

However, I prefer the second approach. Because [conventionally HTML div attributes are written in `kebab-case` (separated with dash)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49823329/10858321) most of the time, in which case you must need to follow the second approach.

Comment: Weirdly (at least to me), it seems it had to be `elem.attributes["output_encrypt"]` - then I tried `elem.attributes.output_encrypt` and it worked. I guess with data attributes you don't need the "data-" part...?

Comment: @richarddmorey, uhm sorry! I should have said that before. I was focused on the error that did not even notice that we do not need to use `data-` to extract the attribute. Because the attributes of `Div` are automatically prefixed with `data-`.